# promise is not returning to defer in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Function is being executed but its not returning the userType value to defer. hence navigating to default page.

> I have two login type say manager admin, based on the response from UI page it should navigate to respective page,this is my requirement.
>   I am even getting response from UI to angular controller but within promise its not fetching those value.
>   Any help could be appreciated

### StudentRepository.js

```
angular.module('student').service('StudentRepository',['$http','$q','$rootScope', function(http, $q,rootScope){
    var user=[];
    this.loginCheck = function(id,password,userType){
        var testVar  = id + "," +password+","+userType;
        var defer = $q.defer(); 
        var studentPromise =  http.put('/Stud/login/',testVar);
        //in testVar also am getting all these values
        studentPromise.then(function(result){ 
         //within this function in result.data am getting null
            user = result.data;
            alert("the result is"+result.data);
            defer.resolve(user);
        });
        return defer.promise;
    };
    }]);
```

### logon.js

```
angular.module('student').controller('LogonController', ['$http','$scope',
   'StudentRepository', '$stateParams', '$state','$rootScope',
    function(http,scope,StudentRepository,stateParams,state,rootScope){

    alert("we r in logon controller ");
    scope.loginCheck  = function(){
    //enter the input values,after submit

    alert("userType"+ scope.user.userType);
        StudentRepository.loginCheck(scope.user.id,scope.user.password,scope.user.userType)
    .then(function (response){
    rootScope.role=response;
    alert(" logon controller"+response);

    if(response == "manager")
    {
        scope.manager=response;
        alert("The user is manager"+" .... "+scope.manager);
        state.go("home");

    }
    else if(response.data == "admin")
    {
        scope.admin=response.data;
        alert("The user is admin"+" ..... "+scope.admin);   
        state.go("home");
    }

    else
    {
        alert(" ID/Password is Invalid...");
        state.go("landingPage");
    }

    });
};
}
]);
```

Comment: should'nt it be `rootScope.role=response;` ? Is it logging anything?  Also you are not handling the error part in `studentPromise.then`

Comment: Am very new to angularjs, exactly am not getting where the problem exists     studentPromise.then(function(result), control is not entering into this function

Comment: The code you have posted is not enough for finding why it is not reaching studentPromise. so if you have show up a working plunkr using which can help you out!

Comment: Are you sure that the API uses a PUT operation? Most login APIs use a POST operation.

Comment: Thank you everyone for trying to help me... Actually mistake was in my server side controller,it was returning null... Hence in angular it was returning to default condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do it more simple because `$http.method` is already returning a Promise.

[$http.put documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put)

you can try this :

```
this.loginCheck = function(id,password,userType){
  var testVar  = id + "," +password+","+userType;
  return http.put('/stud/login/',testVar);    
};
```

Or this if you want handle success and error in your service :

```
 this.loginCheck = function(id,password,userType){
  var testVar  = id + "," +password+","+userType;
  return http.put('/stud/login/',testVar).then(function (response){
     return response // or response.data
 }
  , function (error){
     return error;
  });    
 };
```

I think it should work with tour controller